# Boolean variable naming of price setting

Tags: c#, variables, naming-conventions

I have a boolean variable that flags if a price (on an individual item) should be displayed. I started to name it "DisplayPrice", but that is really more descriptive of the price of the item to be displayed (think: decimal). What are some options here?

I didn't think anything starting with "Is" was appropriate. For example, "IsDisplayPrice" seems more like meta of the price itself, where "IsPriceDisplayed" seems more like a condition than a setting.

ShouldDisplayPrice? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShowPrice`.  Simple to the point.

`ShouldDisplayPrice` is a suggestion.  Kind of like telling the application "I *think* you maybe want to display it, but don't mind me."  It tells future programmers that they are free to make up their own minds about it.  I consider this a wholly dangerous situation as programmers shouldn't be left to their own devices as they tend towards unproductive activities like forking linux or writing windows desktop apps.

`IsPriceDisplayed` and `IsDisplayPrice` are questions that I'm not sure a data point stored in the database can actually answer.  After all, the programmer might not have put the field on the screen.  Setting to true in this situation may cause the universe to explode.

Of course, you could go negative and use `HidePrice` instead.  However, this may be confusing to the feable minded when you have logic such as "`if (!HidePrice) { /*emit price */ }`"

The worst one along these lines is probably `CanPriceBeHidden`.  It's a suggestion, a question and a negative value.  Only to be used if you are feeling particularly snarky.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking IsPriceVisible. ShowPrice seems to me like an action, not a state, for example:

```
if (IsPriceVisible) {
    ShowPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an anal retentive question... I like it :)

How about `CanDisplayPrice`?  We use "Can" and "Is" for boolean variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Chris's answer is good. Also don't forget that this is a good instance where add the XML documentation to your property might come in handy for other coders, if there is any question of ambiguity or subjective naming conventions (as in this case). Just add the old `///` above the property and fill in an explanation.

Also you could go negative and do HidePrice. really any of the suggestions provided here wouldn't be terrible, and everything would be clear with proper XML doc!